# curl not working but not giving any error either

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm working on [Globe Labs API](http://www.globelabs.com.ph) to send an SMS. But before I can send an SMS, the mobile number I want to send message to needs to be subscribed so I can get the `access_token` which will be used in sending SMS.

There are 2 options to subscribe - via SMS or via Web Form. I was able to use first option without any problem. But I can't make the second option work.

According to the [documentation](http://www.globelabs.com.ph/docs/#getting-started-opt-in-via-webform), after the subscriber keyed-in the received confirmation pin on the page and clicked the Confirm button to authorize the subscriber, the page will then be redirected to the redirect_uri of my application, and a Code parameter will be passed(via GET) to it.

Here's the part where I fail to make it work:

> To get the access token, you need to do a POST request via https://developer.globelabs.com.ph/oauth/access_token with your ‘app_id’, ‘app_secret’ and ‘code’ as the parameters. The parameters ‘access_token’ and ‘subscriber_number’ will then be returned to your Redirect URI as a response.

Here's my code:

```
$app_id = '<my_app_id>';
$app_secret = '<my_app_secret>';

$content = array(
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'code' => $this->input->get('code')
);
$url = 'http://developer.globelabs.com.ph/oauth/access_token';

$this->post_to_url($url, $content);

function post_to_url($url, $data) {
   $fields = '';
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');

   $post = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($post);

   curl_close($post);
   if(!$result){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($post) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($post));
    } else {
        $this->Sms_Api_model->save_subscriber_data();
    }
}
```

This is my redirect URL: http://api.forexcargo.us/sms_api/globelabs_api?code=[code]

And the result I get:

> Error: "" - Code:

**EDIT:**

I tried to use a form and send my data via method POST and it worked. So it really might be my curl setup.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use `curl_close($post);` after

Comment: Hi @kenzotenma, it's included in the code after `$result = curl_exec($post);`

Comment: what is `$curl` that you passed in `curl_exec`

Comment: Did you try to follow https://developer.globelabs.com.ph/oauth/access_token in the browser? "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did follow it to directly input it in the browser but I think it will not work since it needs to be POST request.

Comment: @kenzotenma oh, thanks. I changed it but it's still the same.

Comment: "since it needs to be POST request." Maybe but "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved" is a weird error normally you would see more like something like "method not allowed" on a REST service

Comment: First of all, according to documentation you are supposed to make this request to the HTTPS version of the endpoint, but you are using HTTP only. Secondly, _don’t_ assemble query string data yourself, manually - `http_build_query` exists. `CURLOPT_POST, count($data)` is rather nonsense, that option is a boolean one. And check what `$result` contains!

Comment: @CBroe thanks for you helpful inputs. I changed the http to https, I put back `http_build_query` (it was in my code before but I tried to change it thinking it could be a cause), removed `CURLOPT_POST, count($data)`, and checked what `$result` contains using `var_dump()` but it's still the same.

Comment: @RaymondNijland maybe you are right. I also emailed the support to really confirm if the problem lies in the URL. But for now, I want to use all the possible options to make sure there's no problem with my code.

Comment: why would you repeat `curl_exec` in `if` statement. Can't you just do this `if( !$result )`. You've basically executing a connection that you've already closed, which won't work

Comment: @kenzotenma I saw my mistakes and corrected it. I don't get anything still.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried to use a form with method post to see if that will work and it did. So it definitely has something to do with my curl

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being a newbie regarding curl. Apparently, I had to add the following code to see the errors on my code because the URL I'm using has its error checking disabled:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(0);
```

And my new code:

```
function do_post_request($post_data)
{
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    set_time_limit(0);
    $url = 'https://developer.globelabs.com.ph/oauth/access_token';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    // execute!
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($ch);

    // do anything you want with your response
    if($this->json_validator($response) == 1){
        $decode_data = json_decode($response, true);

        $post_data_arr = array('access_token' => $decode_data['access_token'], 'subscriber_number' => $decode_data['subscriber_number']);

        $this->Sms_Api_model->save_subscriber_data($post_data_arr);
        //var_dump(http_response_code(200));
    }
}

$content = [
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'code' => $this->input->get('code')
    ];

$post_request = $this->do_post_request($content);
```

Now it's working and I was able to save the data I received in my database. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: where did that `$this` come from? can you use it without being in an object context??

Comment: @kenzotenma it's because I use it in CodeIgniter.